# PHP exception handling doesn't work properly

Tags: php, exception

I'm using the PHP Exceptions with many try/catch blocks and all works fine, except in one specific snippet.

See the codes below:

*Controller.class*

```
<?php
namespace Controller;

use Business\Exceptions\AppException;
use Business\OTA\Responses\Erros\RS_ERROR;
use Utils\Merge;

class Controller{
    //other methods

    public main(){
        //do stuff
        $resp = $this->merge($con)
    }

    private function merge($con)
    {
        try {
            $merge = new Merge($this->record, $con);
            $merge->sortResponses();
            return $merge->searchResponse;
        } catch (AppException $ex){
            $response = new RS_ERROR($this->client);
            echo ($response);
        }
   }
}
```

*Merge.class* (simplified)

```
<?php
namespace Utils;

use Business\Exceptions\AppException;
use Exception;

class Merge
{

    public $responses;         
    public $conectors;
    public $searchResponse;

    /**
     * Method __construct
     * @param array $conectorResponses 
     * @param $conectors 
     * @throws \Business\Exceptions\AppException
     */
    public function __construct(array $conectorResponses, $conectors)
    {
        $this->responses = $conectorResponses;
        $this->conectors = $conectors;
        $this->searchResponse = array();
        if (empty($this->responses)) {
            $ex = new AppException("Search Not found", '11');
            throw $ex;
        }
    }
```

When I run the code and the call Merge constructor, even when `$this->responses` is empty, the Exception is thrown, but it is not catched in the Controller and I see the notice

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/ws-test/app/Controller/Controller.class.php on line 96

Refers to the line `return $merge->searchResponse;`

When I debug the code, I can use a breakpoint in `throw $ex`, but this is not catched.
Am I doing something wrong? Why the exception is ignored?

I see some similar questions here in SO, but any describe the same problem.

Comment: If you add a `catch (Exception $ex) {}` after the `catch (AppException $ex){` does that catch this exception?

Comment: @RiggsFolly. I had not tried it yet (mea culpa), but I changed to `Exception` right now and then the error is correctly catched, although I do not understand why

Comment: Because that exception is generated by the system and not your manual generation of a AppException. I guess something else has gone wrong in the contructor and therefore the object has not actually been created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is not correct in your code:

```
$this->searchResponse = array();
```

then you return an empty array:

```
return $merge->searchResponse;
```

perhaps you meant:

```
return $merge->responses;
```

---

To make sure you catch all exception, catch all your custom ones first then add `Exception` on the last catch block:

```
try {
   //code
} catch (AppException $ex){
    $response = new RS_ERROR($this->client);
    echo ($response);
}catch (Exception $e){
    var_dump($e);
}
```